# How do I add a node to a point in a circuit in Quartus Prime?

Tags: quartus-ii, quartus

I would like to be able to view not just the output of my circuit in simulation but also an interior node. You can see it in the below diagram. I named the connection "D2".

[image]

Do I have to connect that wire to an output in order to view its value in simulation, or is there another way to make it show up in the Node Finder so I can add it to a wave form?

Comment: Misread your question at first. Could you post a screenshot of the node finder window.

Comment: @TomCarpenter The Node Finder window shows inst, inst5, and inst6, in addition to my inputs and outputs. Would inst5 mean the output of the first latch, in which case I could that? What if the device had multiple outputs?

Comment: Is there a `[+]` sign next to the `inst5`? If so, open that and see if you can find the `Q` signal inside.

Comment: No `[+]`. I'll empirically test whether it is the `Q` value.

Comment: For this simulation at least, inst5 is the same as D2 (which I got by connecting it to an output pin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tom Carpenter suggested, I was able to select the output of an instance in the Node Finder.